# An ideal gas expands into vacuum in an insulated rigid vessel. Which of the followings happens?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, volume, adiabatic

*This question came in the Dhaka university admission exam 2018-19.*

An ideal gas expands into vacuum in an insulated rigid vessel. Which of the following happens?

A. no change of
internal energy

B. a decrease of temperature

C. no change of pressure

D. a change of phase

**Question bank's attempt:**

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

$$\Delta U=-W$$

$$-\Delta U=PdV$$

If $dV$ increases, then $-\Delta U$ will increase, but $\Delta U$ will decrease. So, if the gas expands, then the internal energy will decrease. Consequently, the temperature will also decrease. So, the answer is (B).

**My attempt:**

I don't even understand what the question means. Firstly, if the vessel is rigid (with no movable piston adjusted at the top), then it is an isochoric process, and the volume of the gas must stay constant. The gas can't expand. By rigid vessel, I assume that they mean a rigid vessel with no movable piston adjusted at the top. If that is the case, then the premise of the question is wrong; therefore, making the question wrong from the get-go.

I'll give the question some leeway and assume that they mean a rigid vessel with a piston adjusted at the top. If that is what they meant, they should've said so clearly. Suppose, this is the vessel:

[image]

Even if I assume that a piston is adjusted at the top, what does "expands into vacuum" even mean?

**My questions:**

1. If, by rigid vessel, they mean a rigid vessel with no movable piston adjusted at the top, won't the question be wrong?
2. What do they mean by "expands into vacuum"? *[They probably meant that if we suddenly moved the piston up externally (by our hands, for example), there will be a temporary vacuum created at the upper part of the vessel, and then immediately afterward that temporary vacuum will be filled by the expanding gas. I'm not sure if this is the correct interpretation, though].*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be their point of view, consider a rigid vessel with two chambers seperated by a partition. In this vessel, one of the chambers is filled with the ideal gas and the other chamber is a vacuum. Now the question asks," *what changes will occurr after removing the partion*?"

This is an example for [free expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion) of the ideal gas. As the vessel is insulated the heat absorbed or rejected will be zero i.e., $q=0$. The external pressure acting on the piston is zero ( because the other chamber is a vacuum) . So the work done by the ideal gas will be zero i.e., $w=0$. From first law of thermodynamics, we can prove that change in the internal energy of the system is zero i.e., $\Delta U=0$. But, $\Delta U = nC_v\Delta T$ which implies $\Delta T =0$. So now we can take the advantage of Boyle's law, i.e., $PV=\textrm{constant}$. As the volume of ideal gas in increasing (beacuse it undergoing expansion) the pressure of the ideal gas decreases. As it is an ideal gas it's phase will remains same. So probably the correct answer is "A".